# Exception Handler with isFatal flag

Tags: c#, exception

I want to write an Exception handler in my C# app for both handled and unhandled exceptions. For the handled ones though, I want to be able to specify if the application should shutdown or continue (eg, if database connections are not working, then no point continuing right...). I have observed that the Exception class has something called "Data" (a dictionary) to pass messages, but I am not very convinced that it is where we should specify the flag to shut down the app. I am more leaning towards creating a Custom Exception class with a Boolean property. Data can be used for some custom messages about the exception but does not seem to be a place for communication within the application. I am curious to know if my understanding is right and that is the general way of handling exceptions or is there a better way.

Comment: Please show some code to tell us what you mean when you say "exception handler". That term has several meanings.

Comment: And what kind of exceptions are you talking about? Please show an example. In general, if an exception is thrown, and not handled, then the application should shut down.

Answer (score 0):

If you're making a WinForms app, the initialize the database before the first Form loads in your `Main()` method. If an exception is thrown there, catch it and display a MessageBox to the user informing them that the database connection could not be initialized, and on acceptance, `return` from the `Main()` to keep the form from ever loading. (You could also chain any other things like this before loading the form to make sure everything will work properly once the actual UI starts.)

Other than that, Custom Exception classes are helpful if the default .NET Exceptions do not provide the functionality you need (as in your case), or you want to ensure that custom error handling occurs anytime a type of error occurs. Using the default exceptions could cause overlap with Exceptions that are thrown by the .NET language code and your own. Having a flag like that would work, but it depends on where you'd be catching it up the stack.

Comment: -1: Custom exception classes are _not_ always a good idea. They are only a good idea when it's necessary for a custom exception to be _caught_ and handled differently from built-in exceptions or other custom exceptions.

Comment: Very good point. I did mean about it being when the default Exceptions do not provide what you need. I'll adjust my answer.